# Bootstrap: Auto arrange components without offset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, components

When resizing the window so that some components don't fit on the same line anymore, they are pushed onto the next line, but with an offset. How do I get rid of that?

```
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Just for clarification, I like the behavior the way it is, I just want to get rid of that offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look into the bootstrap.css, then you'll see the following lines:

```
.checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline, .radio-inline + .radio-inline {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

The important Thing is the "+"-operator.

```
.checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline
```

This means, that every ".checkbox-inline"-element that follows directly another ".checkbox-inline"-element, will have a margin of 10px to its left.

So a possible solution could be the Manipulation of the css-file. But another thing, you could do, is adding empty "span"-Elements between the checkboxes.

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"><label>Check me out</label>
</div>
<span></span>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"><label>Check me out</label>
</div>
```

I hope, this was helpful.